# Computer is on for about a minute before windows even begins to boot. What hardware is failing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, hardware-failure

About 2 weeks ago my computer started doing this thing where I press the power button and it's on with the fans etc going for about a minute before the monitor ever turns on and windows begins to boot; if it even boots at all.

I started to think maybe my SSD was failing so I reformated all my drives and installed a fresh copy of windows on an entirely new drive. This issue still exists.

Now I'm wondering is it my GPU? PSU? Games seem to run fine still and the computer isn't shutting down under heavy load.

Any thoughts on what could be failing here? Is there any good way to check all my hardware components for failure?

Comment: You may like to provide detailed specs of your computer including all hardware parts. What if you remove all storage devices like HDD/SSD/DVD Drive etc and just boot with bare minimum components? Just RAM, GPU, Board CPU & PSU? Does it still behave the same way? Also try re-seating the RAM. If you have two RAM sticks try with just one. Alternate between the two. Continue experimenting with removing and attaching each component one by one to check it out.

Comment: I would recommend stress testing your system. I would recommend Stresslinux, which has many tools which can assist with testing of different components. I would start with a RAM check.http://freshcode.club/projects/stresslinux

Answer (score 1):

According to your description "Games seem to run fine still and the computer isn't shutting down under heavy load", there may be no hardware problems, we can troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Set SSD startup as a priority startup item in BIOS.
2. Check the BIOS setting, enable the Fast Boot (or Quick Boot) in BIOS, it looks like this.
   [image]
3. Is our monitor a standalone graphics card + integrated graphics card? Are we plugging the monitor cable into the integrated graphics card?  We should plug the monitor cable to into standalone graphics card.